# Add an ActionListener to a PrimeFaces MenuItem programatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, actionlistener, menuitem

I'm trying to define an action listener programatically to a menuItem which is then used by a menu. Searched on internet for solutions to this, found some examples but there are some methods which aren't been implemented in PF 4.0 (I assume), how can I do this? this I what I have so far...

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MenuTest implements Serializable{

private MenuModel model;

public MenuTest() {
    model = new DefaultMenuModel();

    MenuItem item;

    item = new MenuItem();
    item.setValue("Menuitem 1"); //Error Here -> Can't find method - 
                                 //Only setLabel or setName available
    item.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener()); // Incompatible types
                 /MenuActionListener cant be converted to Action Listener -> Why?

    model.addMenuItem(item); // Can't find method
    model.addElement(item); // Incompatible types - .
              //Menu Item cannot be converted to Menu Element
}

public MenuModel getModel() {
    return model;
}
```

}

My Action Listener Class

```
public class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public MenuActionListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException{
        System.out.println("Test Action Listener called..");
        System.out.println("Source of the Event is ");
    }

}
```

Comment: The types are not the same but since `MenuActionListener` implements `ActionListener`, you can use: `item.addActionListener((ActionListener)new MenuActionListener())`;

Comment: I actually did this, though I get a can't cast exception when running project =/

Comment: Is your ActionListener importing `javax.faces.event.ActionListener` or `java.awt.ActionListener` (or something else)?

Comment: javax.faces.event.ActionListener =/